# Как оптимизировать сайт с gif

Tags: javascript, html, css

На фотке ниже находится та самая gif, для такого формата, нужно было вставить её 4 раза (gif весит 85мб), но почти всю гифку не видно, так как стоит overflow hidden. Но из-за неё начинает очень силтно тупить сайт. Может можно как-то сделать, чтобы оптимизировать сайт? Или же все то что скрыто за overflow не подгружалось ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может, сделать 4 гифки? Или показывать одну, но разделить ее полосами белыми?

Comment: При вставке даже 1 гифки весь сайт лагает

Comment: Ну сам вес гифки довольно большой, потому сайт и тупит. Можете попробовать ее [оптимизировать](https://www.globaldots.com/resources/blog/how-to-optimize-gif-images-for-faster-webpage-loading/)

Comment: почему-бы в 2021 году не конвертировать gif в mp4?